# Convert object to array in Javascript / React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Using REST, I am retrieving an object(`JSON` format) which is to be converted to an array so that it can be inserted into a table.

This is done in the rendering function of React.

The input is updated every N minutes from the back-end.

How do I convert an object to an array?

I need o**nly the values, not the keys**, since the keys are already present as column values beforehand in the table itself.

Comment: have you tried writing any code yet for this question?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) (ECMAScript 2017), but it's not supported by IE (see [browser's compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)).

**Note:** The ECMAScript 6 specification defines in which order the properties of an object should be traversed. [This blog post explains the details](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html).

```js
const map = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

const result = Object.values(map);

console.log(result);
```

If you need to support IE, you can use [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const map = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

const result = Object.keys(map).map((key) => map[key]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, browser compatibility is assumed to be the newest; I think your first method would work. Now I just need to see how I can get the data from the REST api, I have it defined in react as `var tableDataMap = this.props.data.dataMap;` and need to pass it down to a new `const` as yours above, I presume? Along those lines.

Comment: Before you try to do that, learn how to work with async calls in JS. The are promises, generators, and async wait, but you should start with promises.

Comment: Do you have any material for those? If possible. By the way, `        console.log(Object.values(tableDataMap));` produces the REST API data on the browser console... But I have difficulty getting them in the table properly. Anyway.. Too difficult to write here I think.

Comment: This is a tutorial for using fetch and promises to make async calls - [JavaScript Promises: Plain and Simple](https://coligo.io/javascript-promises-plain-simple/).

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure by map you mean the Map object or an ordinary JS object. However, just for variety I would like to mention that the Map objects are mostly (probably always) stringified like `JSON.stringify([...myMap])`. So if you happen to receive a Map object in JSON data may be you should do something like;

```js
var myMap = new Map().set(1,"hey").set(2,"you"),
  mapData = JSON.stringify([...myMap]),
   values = JSON.parse(mapData).map(d => d[1]);
console.log("mapData:",mapData);
console.log("values:",values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set initial value as array firstly. See this example:

```
const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]); // fianal data is array

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchConversations = async () => {
       const res = await axios.get("/conversations/" + user._id);              
       setConversations(res.data);              
    };
    fetchConversations();
  }, [user._id]);
```

`res.data` convert to array by using `useState([])` as initial value and convert to object by using `useState({})`.

And map this array:

```
return (
    <>
       {conversations.map((conv) => 
            (<Conversations key={conv._id} conversation={conv} />))}
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set initial value as array firstly. See this example:

```
const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]); // fianal data is array

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchConversations = async () => {
       const res = await axios.get("/conversations/" + user._id);              
       setConversations(res.data);              
    };
    fetchConversations();
  }, [user._id]);
```

`res.data` convert to array by using `useState([])` as initial value and convert to object by using `useState({})`.

And

return(
{conversations.map((conv) => (

))}
)